# How to download artifacts using an URL in a gitlab job?

Tags: gitlab

In the gitlab documentation some URL's are described for the purpose of downloading artifacts from pipelines [HERE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#access-the-latest-job-artifacts-by-url). They seem to have forgotten to describe HOW to download artifacts given these URLs.

Can it be done in a simple way? Or do I have to install e.g. `wget`, create a token, define a token, use a token?

If someone could give an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation referenced in the question is supposed to be an [REST API call](https://dev.to/drakulavich/gitlab-ci-cache-and-artifacts-explained-by-example-2opi), using the [Job Artifact API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-the-artifacts-archive):

```
GET /projects/:id/jobs/artifacts/:ref_name/download?job=name
```

> To use this in a script definition inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you can use either:
>
> - The `JOB-TOKEN` header with the GitLab-provided `CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable.
>   For example, the following job downloads the artifacts of the test job of the main branch.
>   The command is wrapped in single quotes because it contains a colon `(:)`:
>
> ```yaml
> artifact_download:
> stage: test
> script:
>   - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=test"'
> ```
>
> - Or the `job_token` attribute with the GitLab-provided `CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable.
>   For example, the following job downloads the artifacts of the test job of the main branch:
>
> ```yaml
> artifact_download:
>  stage: test
>  script:
>    - 'curl --location --output artifacts.zip >"https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=test&job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"'
> ```

---

But the `artifact:` directive is meant to store data in the job workspace, for a new iteration of the job to get back, in the same folder.

No "download" involved, as illustrated in the article "[GitLab CI: Cache and Artifacts explained by example](https://dev.to/drakulavich/gitlab-ci-cache-and-artifacts-explained-by-example-2opi)" by [Anton Yakutovich](https://twitter.com/drakulavich).
As such, no `curl`/`wget`/`TOKEN` should be needed to access an artifact stored by a previous job execution.

Comment: To use that I need to install 'curl' first. That means, to use a specific image, install curl... Is there no other way? I mean, I am in a gitlab CI itself! There should be an easy way to receive artifacts from the same gitlab setup? No?

Comment: In addition, I am not authorized to do the `curl` as the `gitlab` instance I am using is not public. I need to be authorized to use that without our company.

Comment: Do you have wget?

Comment: `curl` or `wget` hardly matter. It looks like the gitlab CI is unable to access its own 'area'. After all, it is the SAME pipeline in the SAME repo. I should not get any permission issues...

Comment: @Alex The point of my answer is that: it is a network call to a remote API. You need something able to do that network call.

Comment: Not sure I understand

Comment: @Alex The documentation you are referencing in your question is about a REST API call (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/index.html). So to your question `do I have to install e.g. wget` + token, I would say, to my knowledge, yes.

Comment: There is no other way to use artifacts from the SAME pipeline in the SAME repo which did run earlier? I have to deal with TOKEN and permissions etc? That is the only way?

Comment: @Alex From https://dev.to/drakulavich/gitlab-ci-cache-and-artifacts-explained-by-example-2opi, a new iteration of the job would not need to download anything: it would find the artifacts right where the previous instance left them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239361/discussion-between-alex-and-vonc).

Comment: @AFP_555 Downvote does not require justification. All that matters is that my answer helps the OP. Or other future readers.